# ORACLE: Listener could not hand off Connection error

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-xe

Here is my oracle 11.2.0 config

Listener.ora:

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = ORCL))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

Tnsnames.ora

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )
```

I am starting OracleServieORCL as admin user on windows 8 machine. Then on the same system i am using sqldevloper (4.0.1) to connect to SID ORCL with user name system and password admin (admin is the password given during installation)

I get error ORA-12518:TNS:Listener could not hand off client connection.

I tried to reinstall the software but that did not help. I got Java 8 (8-101) version installed on my box.

```
lsnrctl services

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 14-SEP-2016 12:02:11

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: <system_name>, pid: 2808>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST= <system_name>)(PORT=52707))
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:17 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: You said <...I am starting OracleServieXE...> this means that your service_name is XE. Replace "SERVICE_NAME = ORCL" with "SERVICE_NAME = XE". I am not sure this will solve your problem as the ORA message say that the problem is something else. Could you run "lsnrctl services" in the CMD and show the output?

Comment: "lsnrctl service"  shows that your service name is xe - so try to replace in your tnsnames.ora "SERVICE_NAME = ORCL" with "SERVICE_NAME = XE" if after this you will get error during connection we will try to solve it.

Comment: Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Comment: please ensure that you have only one listener running on your host. If you have just restarted your listener - wait 1 min in order Oracle to register within the listener. The ORA error looks strange for me as I see from "lsnrctl services" that xe is registered. Another idea is: 1)remove the listener.ora file 2)restart the listener service 3)wait 1 min 4) try to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after days of debugging, finally got to know the installation did not register with system registry and when i re installed it via admin privileges it worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.  I added the "oracle home" account to the "Administrator" group, then restarted the listener and database.  That fixed the problem.  In my case, I was running Oracle 12c, Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score -1):

This has happened to me and I fixed it by replacing `localhost` by `127.0.0.1` in listener.ora (then restart the listener). I made the same change in `tnsnames.ora` and then I was able to connect successfully.

Also please replace "SERVICE_NAME" with "SID" in your tnsnames.ora file since you're trying to connect using SID.